# FILESTREAM shared folder can not be accessed using listener name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, filestream, azure-vm

I have AlwaysOn configured in SQL Server 2014 and enabled Filestream in both nodes (node 1 and node2) as shown here:

[Enable and Configure FILESTREAM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923.aspx) (MSDN Library)

I have named the shared folder name "MYSHAREDSQLFILES".

I can access the folder using below path whenever *node 1* is Primary

```
   \\**node1**\MYSHAREDSQLFILES
```

So the user must know which node is primary before accessing the folder. I saw in MSDN that *filestream is partially supported*:

[FILESTREAM and FileTable with AlwaysOn Availability Groups (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510261(v=sql.110).aspx)

> In an AlwaysOn availability group, however, the name of the computer is virtualized by using a Virtual Network Name, or VNN. When the computer is the primary replica in an availability group, and databases in the availability group contain FILESTREAM data, then a VNN-scoped share is also created to provide access to the FILESTREAM data. This does not affect Transact-SQL access to FILESTREAM data. However applications that use file system APIs have to use the VNN-scoped share, which has a path in the following format:

```
    \\<VNN>\<filestream_share_name>
```

What is VNN here? I know its Virtual Network name but when i try it does not resolve. Is it virtual network from azure?

The link explains how to provide access
[Need to make sense of FileTable permissions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107522/need-to-make-sense-of-filetable-permissions) but did not work for me :(

Comment: Are you asking how to find out what your virtual network name is or are you having trouble connecting to the share using the VNN? If you don't know the VNN, it is the name of the listener.